# Copy and Paste Using Values

Tags: excel, vba

I have what I hope to be a simple question. I have the following code below. This code copies column L and Pastes it back into Column L in values format. This way I can get rid of the formula. My Countif Code needs this to count the number of months in column L (January, February, March, etc.). When I run this code from the macro screen it works great. when I run it from a button the pasted values only fill in rows one and two leaving the rest of the rows in column L blank.(there are 600+ rows). any ideas on why my code works from the macro screen but not when using a button? I want to make it so that it is user friendly to my co-workers. Thank you, Matt

```
  LastRow = Sheets("HR Data Detail").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
  Worksheets("HR Data Detail").Range("L2:L" & LastRow).Copy
  Worksheets("HR Data Detail").Range("L2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: Step through the code so that  you can check the value of LastRow, or print it out using Debug.Print. Is there anything else we should know about your spreadsheet or code?

Comment: The data in column A is determining your LastRow.  Andy has you going down the right path.

Comment: Also test it by using a fixed row number rather than determining LastRow.

Comment: This is working? That should be `Paste:= xlPasteValues`

Comment: You are correct Andy. When I replaced Last row with L2000 it pasted all the way down. LastRow worked in an earlier formula which confuses me. Thanks for the Help. I will Redefine LastRow. or use finRow.

Answer (score 1):

Code includes a more standard last row indicator and to simply set the column equal to it's own value (faster approach). You can also do some formatting inside the `With` block if needed with ease

---

```
Sub RemoveFormula()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HR Data Detail")

Dim LRow As Long
LRow = ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With ws.Range("L2:L" & LRow)
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the Tips. I could use this in a lot of my Code. I will switch this around. Matt

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub RemoveFormula()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HR Data Detail") 'reference wanted sheet
        With .Range("L2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column L range from row 2 down to its last not empty value
            .Value = .Value ' remove formulas and leave values
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```